# my react.js app is coming blank trying to seed with an external js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

I just started studying react, so I picked up the book Fullstack react by Anthony Accomozzio et al, with the latest version on January 13, 2020. I created the react app with `npx create-react-app` I am stuck on the part of 'making product data driven', I'm trying to seed data from an external file seed.js using props, but it returns a blank screen. But runs if data is hard encoded.

App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import './seed';

function App() {
  const product = window.Seed.products[1];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Product 
        id = {product.id}
        title = {product.title}
        decription = {product.description}
        url = {product.url}
        votes = {product.votes}
        submitterAvatarUrl = {product.submitterAvatarUrl}
        productImageUrl = {product.productImageUrl}
      />
      
      
    </div>
  );
}

const Product = () => {
  return (

    <div className = 'item'>
        <div className = 'image'>
          <img src = {this.props.productImageUrl} />
        </div>
        <div className = 'middle aligned content'>
          <div className = 'header'>
            <a>
              <i className = 'large caret up icon' />
            </a>
            {this.props.votes}
          </div>
          <div className = 'description'>
            <a href = {this.props.url}>
              {this.props.title}
            </a>
            <p>
              {this.props.description}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className='extra'>
            <span>Submitted by:</span>
            <img
              className='ui avatar image'
              src = {this.props.submitterAvatarUrl}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  );
    
}

export default App;
```

The seed.js that has the data:

```
window.Seed = (function (){

    function generateVoteCount() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 15);
      }
    
    const products = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Yellow Pail',
            description: 'On-demand sand castle construction expertise.',
            url: '#',
            votes: generateVoteCount(),
            submitterAvatarUrl: 'images/avatars/daniel.jpg',
            productImageUrl: 'images/products/image-aqua.png',
        },
        ...
    ];
    return { products: products };
}());
```

Is the codes deprecated for the react version?

Comment: what do you mean by it returns blank page if data is not hardcoded? Because let's think straight, if you try to get some data from a file but file is empty, I think it is expected that you don't get anything because there is nothing in the file. so blank page is normal?

Comment: Dennis Karadag the data is in the seed.js file, kindly check the code above, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Product` component is a functional component which means there is no `this.props`.

You'll need to take in the `props` as an argument and then you can use `prop.xxx` to access the values.

```js
const Product = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <div className="image">
        <img src={props.productImageUrl} />
      </div>
      <div className="middle aligned content">
        <div className="header">
          <a>
            <i className="large caret up icon" />
          </a>
          {props.votes}
        </div>
        <div className="description">
          <a href={props.url}>{props.title}</a>
          <p>{props.description}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="extra">
          <span>Submitted by:</span>
          <img className="ui avatar image" src={props.submitterAvatarUrl} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```